# Pandas pivot table maximum value

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following pivot table (df):

```
Region     North      South
Col                                
A          33.330367   9.178917
B         -36.157025  -27.669988
C         -38.480206  -46.089908
D         -47.986764  -32.324991
E          323.209834  28.486310
F          34.936147   4.072872
G          0.983977   -14.972555
```

In order to find the maximum value, I do:

```
df.max()
```

It returns:

```
Region
North     323.209834
South      28.486310
dtype: float64
```

Is there a way to just return the maximum value i.e. 323?

Comment: Does `df.max().max()` work?

Comment: thanks! sadly it does work, I say sadly because the syntax is not intuitive to me. if you want to put in an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I mean it is intuitive, perhaps not elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max()` twice:

```
df.max().max()
```

Alternatively, since we are already assuming that all the elements are numerical, we can get the underlying numpy array and thus its maximum value using a single call to `max()`:

```
df.values.max()
```